# Using a field for populating the meta-tags of view pages

Tags: views, theming, meta-tags

I've got taxonomy pages that are emulated by real views. The vocabulary terms have an additional field "field_meta_description", where meta-description tags can be added. On the view page of each term, this field should be used to populate the content of the html tag `<meta name="description"/>`.
How can this be accomplished? I know there are some modules out there like [metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag), but I am looking for a custom way to do it by lightweight self-coding.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Drupal 7:

You can go for implementing hook_page_alter() in your theme's template.php and use [drupal_add_html_head()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7.x) to insert your own metatags. Following the link you will find lots of exmples in the comments.